# Mqtt connection gives 403 for aws IOT Pre-Signed URL

Tags: websocket, mqtt, iot, http-status-code-403, aws-iot

I have aws lambda function that generates IOT websocket URL as below.

```
const v4 = require('aws-signature-v4');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const WSSURL = v4.createPresignedURL(
        'GET',
        process.env.IOT_ENDPOINT_HOST.toLowerCase(),
        '/mqtt',
        'iotdevicegateway',
        crypto.createHash('sha256').update('', 'utf8').digest('hex'),
        {
            'key': process.env.IOT_ACCESS_KEY,
            'secret': process.env.IOT_SECRET_KEY,
            'protocol': 'wss',
            'region': process.env.IOT_AWS_REGION,
        }
    );
```

and I have mqttjs at client side that use this url and try to connect web socket as following.

```
var options = {
        will    : {
            topic  : LAST_WILL_TOPIC,
            payload: getMessageString(wss_userId, wss_email, wss_userType, {})
        },
        clientId: wss_userType + '||' + wss_userId
    };

    wssClient = mqtt.connect(WSSURL, options);
```

This code was working perfect before few months but now connection doesn't initiate and gives following error

```
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

Comment: Form last few days error started again and reason for that was AWS has changed IOT endpoint URL. kindly double check that part also if this error is happening again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our team have run into this issue recently too.

The problem in the `aws-signature-v4` module with version > 1.2.0.

Here is a [code](https://github.com/department-stockholm/aws-signature-v4/blob/5ed9870fa71353eecce50d2882969396a81a4955/index.js#L161):

```
`options.sessionToken = options.sessionToken || process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN;`
```

AWS lambda by default has a `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` in `process.env`

You should use STS to assume role and use sessionToken from it

```
import v4 from 'aws-signature-v4' // ^1.3.0
import STS from 'aws-sdk/clients/sts'

const { IOT_ENDPOINT_HOST, IOT_ROLE_ARN } = process.env
const sts = new STS()

const createSocketUrl = async () => {
  const data = await sts
    .assumeRole({
      RoleArn: IOT_ROLE_ARN,
      RoleSessionName: `some-role-session-name`,
      DurationSeconds: 3600
    })
    .promise()

  return v4.createPresignedURL(
    'GET',
    IOT_ENDPOINT_HOST,
    '/mqtt',
    'iotdevicegateway',
    '',
    {
      key: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secret: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
      protocol: 'wss'
    }
  )
}
```

or if you don't want to use STS

```
import v4 from 'aws-signature-v4' // ^1.3.0

const { IOT_ENDPOINT_HOST, IOT_ACCESS_KEY_ID, IOT_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY } = process.env

const createSocketUrl = () => {
  const { AWS_SESSION_TOKEN } = process.env

  delete process.env['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN']

  const url = v4.createPresignedURL(
    'GET',
    IOT_ENDPOINT_HOST,
    '/mqtt',
    'iotdevicegateway',
    '',
    {
      key: IOT_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secret: IOT_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      protocol: 'wss'
    }
  )
  process.env['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN'] = AWS_SESSION_TOKEN

  return url
}
```

Comment: I tried without using STS. but still it throws the error. I downgraded to 1.1.0 but still the same error is there. Any other reason as to why it throws 403?